# Laravel custom attribute in Model for Scaling image using Cloudinary URL

Tags: php, laravel, cloudinary

In my web app I am using Cloudinary for image storing. Image uploading is working properly but i want to create a custom attribute for image so when getting back the image url from the database with some modification with width and height.

The link of a image: https://res.cloudinary.com/wokong/image/upload/v1568570430/storyHeader/cxjir4g9tkaa8xepxodg.jpg

which is stored in database but when it fetch from the database, It should come with some scaling so that It wont take much time for website loading.

here is my StoryModel:

```
class Story extends Model
{
    use Commentable, Searchable;
    /**
     * The attributes that are mass assignable.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $fillable = [
        'title',
        'summary',
        'content',
        'created_at',
        'story_statuses_id',
        'image', 'language',
        'likes',
        'views',
        'url_key',
    ];



    /**
     * The attributes that should be cast to native types.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $casts = [
        'is_public' => 'boolean',
    ];
```

I dont understand how to use it anyone can help?

Comment: Based on my understanding of your problem, i would recommend creating multiple images with the scale you want and upload it. ie) `cxjir4g9tkaa8xepxodg-160x160.jpg`, `cxjir4g9tkaa8xepxodg240x240.jpg` etc

Comment: If I understand correctly, you want to modify the url to a scaled version before sending it with the response?

Comment: right @Jerodev I want this actually

Comment: But i dont want to store the scaled images to again cloudinary. I just want this for user experince @Cerlin

Comment: How could I make that using a custom attribute??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cloudinary supports runtime image resizing

As per their documentation instead of this

https://res.cloudinary.com/wokong/image/upload/v1568570430/storyHeader/cxjir4g9tkaa8xepxodg.jpg

use

https://res.cloudinary.com/wokong/image/upload/w_100,h_100,c_fit/v1568570430/storyHeader/cxjir4g9tkaa8xepxodg.jpg

As you can see, i have added `/w_100,h_100,c_fit/` after `upload` to instruct Cloudinary to do the resizing on the fly

`w` is for width, `h` is for height and `c` is for scale type to be used while cropping

You can find the documentation [here](https://cloudinary.com/cookbook/resize_an_image)

**UPDATE 1**

Something like this should do it

```
$default_url = "https://res.cloudinary.com/wokong/image/upload/v1568570430/storyHeader/cxjir4g9tkaa8xepxodg.jpg";

$width = 100;
$height = 100;

echo str_replace("/upload", "/upload/w_".$width.",h_".$height.",c_fit", $default_url);
```

**UPDATE 2**

Your model will look like

```
class Story extends Model
{
    use Commentable, Searchable;
    /**
     * The attributes that are mass assignable.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $fillable = [
        'title',
        'summary',
        'content',
        'created_at',
        'story_statuses_id',
        'image', 'language',
        'likes',
        'views',
        'url_key',
    ];



    /**
     * The attributes that should be cast to native types.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $casts = [
        'is_public' => 'boolean',
    ];

    public function getImageForWebAttribute()
    {
        $width = 100; // You can keep this info in app config
        $height = 100;

        // Here i am assuming `image` is where you store Cloudinary url
        return str_replace("/upload", "/upload/w_".$width.",h_".$height.",c_fit", $this->image);
    }
}
```

and you can call it like

```
$story->image_for_web
```

Documentation for laravel custom mutators can be found [here](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/eloquent-mutators#defining-an-accessor)

Comment: This much i understand but how to make that custom attribute so that it will autometically get the "cxjir4g9tkaa8xepxodg.jpg" from the store link in database or anyother ways. I know the link but Code wise how to do it !!!!

Comment: And also i need to store the actual size of the image in cloudinary but when it will return it should scaled for that reason i need a custom attribute, there i am getting stucked.

Comment: `$story` is the model you queried from the database. Since you have not shared any logic about querying, i just posted that

Comment: thanks brother its working. I changed it in resource file

Comment: brother i am a new person to Laravel and web development so... and also a connection request on linkedn please check that i want to learn more from you if any doubts will be there really I wll be gratefull to u bro. name: Rashmi Ranjan Sahoo

Answer (score 1):

Instead of saving the whole URL of the uploaded image in your database, you can save the `public_id` returned in the upload response.
Then you can just use Cloudinary's SDK to generate the transformation URLs for you, by passing the desired transformation parameters to the `cloudinary_url()` Helper function, along with the image's `public_id`.

For example, let's assume that you want to generate a URL of an image which its `public_id` is `sample`. In addition, you want that the image will be delivered with the best format possible, based on the client's device and browser. You would also like to use Cloudinary's automatic quality algorithm and scale the image down to a width of 500px while retaining its original aspect ratio.
You can achieve it by using the following code:

```
$url = cloudinary_url('sample', array(
  'fetch_format' => 'auto',
  'quality' => 'auto',
  'crop' => 'scale',
  'width' => 500 
));
```

`echo $url;` will print the following:

```
http://res.cloudinary.com/<cloud_name>/image/upload/c_scale,f_auto,q_auto,w_500/sample
```

If you wish to generate the whole `<img>` tag using the SDK, you can utilize `cl_image_tag()` as an alternative to the URL only output of `cloudinary_url()`.

Here's the [link](https://cloudinary.com/documentation/php_image_manipulation#deliver_and_transform_images) to the relevant section in Cloudinary's documentation with some more examples on how to use both `cl_image_tag()` and `cloudinary_url()`.

Answer (score 0):

Okay just an additional help for ...

Say for instance you attached $images to a view from the controller in laravel
you could generate fixed width and height on the fly via the url and attach to bootstrap grid system..

`

```
     <div class="col-6 col-md-4 col-lg-3">
            <a href="{{$image->image_url}}">                     
            @php
            $url = $image->image_url;
            @endphp
<img class="img img-fluid" src="{{ str_replace("/upload", "/upload/w_350,h_220,q_70,c_scale", $url) }}" alt="">
                </a>    

           

        </div>
```

`

You could also set this attributes of the image via the controller method using
Cloudder::show(Cloudder::getPublicId(), ["width" => $width, "height"=>$height])